# How to create a function that will kill the clicked fucntion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right, this is slightly challenging and I'm not sure if its even possible.

But here's the scenario:

I have multiple click functions in my jquery code like so:

```
$(document).on('click','.myelement',function(e){


/*my code goes here*/

});
```

Now, I need to create one single function that will check for something.

like so:

```
checkforsomething function (){

if(something positive happens){

/*all good and do nothing*/

}else{

/*STOP/KILL the clicked function and give an error*/

alert('error happend');

}
}
```

Now I need to use this function in all of my click functions like so:

```
$(document).on('click','.myelement',function(e){

checkforsomething();

/*my code goes here*/

});
```

Thats' it.

Could someone please advice on this? is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Your question title is slightly different from your question body

Comment: @vol7ron, I just don't know how to KILL/STOP the clicked function IF the criteria doesn't meet.

Comment: `return checkforsomething()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have checkForSomething return true or false indicating whether to continue or not, then have the event listener decide based on that value what to do.

```
function checkForSomething() {
  if (something positive happens) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

$(document).on('click','.myelement',function(e)
  if (!checkforsomething()) {
    alert('error happened');
    return;
  }

  /*my code goes here*/
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault);

```
$(document).on('click','.myelement', function(event){
    if(something positive happens){
        /*all good and do nothing*/
    }else{
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

When handling events you do not want to return false. It might work here, but when there are multiple events for the same element (or maybe children of that element), it will result in weird stuff. So in case of events: `preventDefault()`.

If you want to use it as a function in a conditional check, you can return true/false:

```
if( myCustomFunction() ){ /* do something */ }
```

This is because there are no other events being blocked like this, you've (simply put) only moved the contents of the if-condition to a function. The condition checks for true/false.

Comment: Why do you think `preventDefault` is what is beign sought?

Comment: this gives me erro: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function` on the very first line which is `checkforsomething function (event){`

Comment: Yes, you have to define the function before the name. I copied your example. Fixed it now.

Comment: @vol7ron: Because OP was talking about eventhandling. I split it into two examples now.

Comment: Ah. I interpreted his question to mean a user-event to cancel another user, something like a stop watch. I don’t think _preventDefault_ would be suitable there